# Angular component doesn't refresh UI

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code structure:

- component1.ts

```
<div class="column-3">
            <div class="fr">
              <a
                class="a-notification"
                [class.a-not-notification]="changeColorClassWhenNotValues()"
                (click)="openHeldCommissionModal()"
                >Held Commissions
                <div
                  class="commission-counter"
                  [class.commission-counter-blue]="changeColorClassWhenNotValues()"
                >
                  {{ heldDetailsReportCount }}
                </div>
                <dv-octicon
                  icon="arrow-right"
                  class="arrow-right-icon"
                  width="15"
                  height="15"
                ></dv-octicon>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
<dv-modal id="heldCommisionReport">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <dv-held-report
        #heldReportComponent
        [modalId]="'heldCommisionReport'"
        [workgroupName]="''"
      >
      </dv-held-report>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
</dv-modal>
```

Then in the `dv-held-report` I have the following HTML:

```
 <h3 class="m-2-vertical">
    Held Commissions Report for {{ name }}
  </h3>
```

When you click on the link the `openHeldCommissionModal()` method is called:

```
openHeldCommissionModal() {
    if (this.viewAsUser) {
      this.heldReportComponent.repId = this.viewAsUser.id
      this.heldReportComponent.name = this.viewAsUser.name
      this.heldReportComponent.isNotViewAsUser = false
      this.heldReportComponent.loggedInUserName = this.loggedUserName
      this.heldReportComponent.detectChanges()
    } else {
      this.heldReportComponent.repId = this.loggedUser.id
      this.heldReportComponent.name = this.loggedUserName
      this.heldReportComponent.isNotViewAsUser = true
      this.heldReportComponent.loggedInUserName = this.loggedUserName
      this.heldReportComponent.detectChanges()
    }
    this.modalService.open('heldCommisionReport')
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
```

And in the `heldReportComponent` I have the `detectChanges()` method:

```
detectChanges() {
    this.cd.detectChanges()
  }
```

The thing is I need to do this because you can have multiple `component1` in the page, so I need to set those values every time you click on the link.
The `name` value is updated in the component but it never reflect to the UI, any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: try using `OnChange` life cycle in the `heldReportComponent` and in there you can access the new values

Comment: @Kardon63 Thanks, I can access the values set previously, the problem is the UI doesn't refresh when I change the name property

Comment: from where is the `name` property is coming, is it the same for `this.heldReportComponent.name`?

Comment: Yes is the same, is a property on the heldReportComponent

Comment: okk then send it like this `[modalId]="heldCommisionReport"` and in the `dv-held-report` try to do this  `Held Commissions Report for {{ modalId.name }}`

Comment: @Kardon63 the problem with that is that you can have multiple `component1` and if it is passed like you say the values doesn't change